# Unstable behavior in forecast::nnetar when p = 0

Tags: r

Using the `forecast` package version 8.15, running the following lines of code:

```
set.seed(42)
fit <- nnetar(nottem,p = 0,P = 2) 
fcast <- forecast(fit,h = 24)
```

(after calling `library(forecast)` of course) generates very oddly inconsistent results for me.

I realize that `p = 0` is not really what `nnetar()` expects, since the documentation says `The inputs are for lags 1 to p` and indeed to code implicitly assumes `p > 0` in using expressions like `1:p`.

So an error would be a reasonable expectation. However, what I find is the `nnetar()` always runs without error or warning and `forecast()` on the resulting object **usually** returns the same set of forecasted values (which are likely nonsense, but at least consistent), but very rarely will return the following error:

```
> fcast <- forecast(fit,h = 24) 
Error in forecast.nnetar(fit, h = 24) : 
  I can't forecast when there are missing values near the end of the series.
```

Stepping through `forecast::forecast.nnetar` seems to reveal that occasionally a forecasted value of `NaN` is produced which is then incorporated into subsequent lags, but I can't seem to determine why or under what conditions the `NaN` is generated in the first place.

Does anyone know what the source of this behavior is?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a combination of inputs that was not anticipated by the package, and the unstable behavior was the result of hard coding sequences like `1:p` and not checking for values like `p = 0`.

This [issue](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/935) and [pull request](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/pull/936) were created to address this and in subsequent versions the package should allow models with only seasonal lags.